# GenericObjectPool : borrowObject method when machine gets down

Tags: redis, connection-pooling, lettuce

I am using below code to create a Redis connection pool

```
GenericObjectPool<StatefulRedisConnection> poolConnections = ConnectionPoolSupport.createGenericObjectPool(
                () -> client.connect(), genericObjectPoolConfig);
System.out.println(new Date()+ "..gettign conn from pool..11")              
StatefulRedisConnection connection = poolConnections.borrowObject();
```

It is working fine. However, in 1 use case when redis machine went down then it take `borrowObject` takes 10 sec to throw exception. I know it may be due to redis lettuce implementation.

Sun Jul **05 17:35:45** IST 2020..gettign conn from pool..11

Sun Jul **05 17:35:55** IST 2020Exception in pushInList() : io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 10.32.17.242:11896

Any one suggest how to reduce this time. I want it to throw exception in less than 10 sec. Is there any configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the cause of a socket timeout. In the Lettuce documentation [here](https://lettuce.io/core/6.1.0.RELEASE/api/constant-values.html#io.lettuce.core.SocketOptions.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT) you can see the default connect timeout is 10 seconds.

You can customize this default socket timeout by updating your RedisClient. In the example below I changed the timeout to be one second.

```
SocketOptions socketOptions = SocketOptions.builder().connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).build();
ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions.builder().socketOptions(socketOptions).build();
RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create(DefaultClientResources.builder().build());
redisClient.setOptions(clientOptions);
```